# Can I divide part of the /dev/sda/home?

Tags: centos, lvm

I have a CentOS7.2 server, and when I install the system, I did not take notice of the disk, now I have a big `/dev/centos/home`:

```
[root@controller dev]# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centos/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                centos
  LV UUID                WofWvD-KQEG-hyaf-TSvf-bLxW-d6Gh-onWriz
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2017-08-30 12:40:47 +0800
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                7.88 GiB
  Current LE             2016
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centos/home
  LV Name                home
  VG Name                centos
  LV UUID                gZlLHM-bWuj-8lXu-8ete-VpZI-zz1w-3AC5rP
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2017-08-30 12:40:47 +0800
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                873.08 GiB
  Current LE             223509
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centos/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                centos
  LV UUID                PKqlOW-SIa8-df24-AVbl-BZMG-n0dn-89kjB3
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2017-08-30 12:40:51 +0800
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                50.00 GiB
  Current LE             12800
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0
```

Now, I want to divide the `/dev/centos/home`, isolate part of it to be a VG, so I can use it as other usage. Such as use it to `pvcreate`.

I don't know whether I can divide the `/dev/centos/home`, because I scare loss data, or break the operate system. But I really need a VG from there to `pvcreate`, or if there is a other method to do that.

Comment: What filesystem is in place (XFS/Ext4/different?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close all programs that use this volume. In the system must be only the root user (safest way might be to comment out `/home` in `/etc/fstab`, then have a reboot, log as root as [Archemar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/79818/archemar) has mentioned below. See more in comments)

First you need to unmount partition:

```
umount /dev/centos/home
```

Then check filesystem (if you skip this step the there may be data loss):

```
e2fsck -fy /dev/centos/home
```

Resize partition:

```
resize2fs /dev/centos/home 50G
```

where `50g` is desired size after shrinking. This size must be greather then used space on partition (see output of `df -h` and set up size a bit more of used space ).

Reduce logical partition:

```
lvreduce -L 51G /dev/centos/home
```

**pay attention**: partition size with `lvreduce` more than with `resize2fs`.

Run `resize2fs` again (to use remaining of ~1G space):

```
resize2fs /dev/centos/home
```

Mount volume:

```
mount -a
```

---

**You need to backup all data before this changes!**

Comment: `close all programs that use this volume`, what do you mean of it?  I don't know what processes on this `/dev/centos/home`, how to close?

Comment: @244boy, it's just a caution. Use `ps -aux` to list all running proccesses and in the last column you'll see where proccess are placed. Also use `lsof` to see what files are in used currently. If you do not installed some unstandard software earlier you do not need to care about it

Comment: @EgorVasilyev safest way might be to comment out `/home` in `/etc/fstab`, then have a reboot, log as root (or alternative sodu-able user having `$HOME` in a temporary directory), and proceed as you instruct.

Comment: alos note that OP want to create a new PG, your method will allow new LV.

Comment: @Archemar, I supplemented my answer with your recommendations